# Static posion of background image when height of div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This `<div class="container">` has a background image.

In this container I have a form .

When I click submit form I show a message box to indicate success , this message box changes the height of container so the background image moves, how can I prevent the background image from moving when it appears?

This is the html :

```
<div class="container">

<form ................ </form>
<div class="successfulmessagebox">......</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for container :

```
.container {

  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 193px;
  padding-bottom: 237px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(49, 43, 61, 0.89)), url("../image/back.jpg");
  background-size: auto auto, cover;
}
```

Comment: `background-position`?

Comment: you may use `position:absolute` for success message and position it.! This will not affect the `container`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class in your CSS .

```
.successfulmessagebox
{
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example will give you start up.!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {

        $('.success').show();
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:240px;     background:url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/83f035c0ea91a761fbfcd67482f9b848?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
    background-size:cover;
}
input{margin:5px 0px;}
.success {
    display:none;
    position:absolute; /*====POSITION:ABSOLUTE=======*/
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    /*position anywhere inside container*/
    left:10px;
    /*position anywhere inside container*/
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="">
        <input type="text" name="">
        <input type="text" name="">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="success">Success</div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.!